# How to map a local Ubuntu Server in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, localhost

I am currently running Ubuntu Server using Oracle's VirtualBox. I would like to map a network drive to my local Ubuntu Server in Windows 8.1. I can connect to my server using PuTTy just fine. I can also view my site in my browser just fine. I have Apache2 and openSSH installed. I can access my site via browser by `http://localhost/`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possible problems.  One is your Virtual Box configuration.  You will need to enable folder sharing for the virtual.  If you are attempting to do this via network, you will need to install SAMBA on your Ubuntu instance in order to get Ubuntu & Windows to play nicely with each other.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways of doing this but yes windows sharing (samba) is the best way. There is another way to is to use filezilla with port 22 and use your ssh username/password

easy guide to samba on ubuntu, should work on latest too and on server
http://scriptcult.com/archives_147/article_548-samba-quick-setup-on-ubuntu-1004.htm

when you have gotten your samba up, you can mount it as a network drive just like a share on a windows server